# Firebase Swift 3.0 data read unwrapping issue

Tags: firebase

```
dbRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot in
     for thingy in snapshot.children {
       let thingyFinal = thingy as? FIRDataSnapshot
         print(thingyFinal)
}})
```

My database structure is as follows:

`->mung-37e2c: {
  "users": {
    "kimkardashian": "stuff",
    "donaldtrump": "stuff"
  },
  goals: {
    "goal1" : "stuff",
    "goal2" : "stuff"
  }
}`

What I cannot wrap my head around is that the error is triggered by the first line of my code:

```
dbRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot in
```

Since I am not force unwrapping here, why is the unwrapping error being triggered. Also, the database has not nil values.

Comment: what is the error? what is dbref?

Comment: Sorry, dbref is the Firebase database reference object                                    let dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
The error is exactly: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
It occurs on the first line of the code I posted in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your code to :-

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().observe(.value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
 for thingy in snapshot.children {
   let thingyFinal = thingy as? FIRDataSnapshot
     print(thingyFinal)
   }
})
```

Comment: For some reason, it always pull nil even though there is content in the database. What's even stranger is I have another function that's identical  and it DOES pull data from the database. To me, it seems like a spurious bug.